# How to validate if a record exists when issuing a REST update request using spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest, jdbctemplate

I have a simple database table `users` with 3 columns:

```
| id | username | nationality | 
|  1 |   John   | American    | 
|  2 |   Doe    | English     |
```

I want to issue an update via a `POST` request to `http://mysite/users/2/nationality`

Now my initial approach was to do a single query

`UPDATE users SET nationality="French" WHERE id=2;` followed by a query for the updated object `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2;` then return the updated object in the response.

The problem is the `id` passed in the request may not exist in my database. **How should I validate if a user exists in the database?**

1. Should I just check if the query returns an object?
2. Should I validate the update first for the affected rows (affected
   rows will be zero if the no change was made to the data to be
   updated so  I can't throw a `UserNotFoundException` in that case)?
3. Is it better to issue a query before the update just to check if the
   row exists then update then query the updated row?

> ```
>   public void updateRecord(Long id, String username) {  
>  String updateSql = "UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE id = ?";  
>  JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
>    Object[] params = { username, id};  
>     int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIGINT};  
>     int rows = template.update(updateSql, params, types);  
>     System.out.println(rows + " row(s) updated.");  
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you always need the update to return the updated object in the response, then option 1 seems like a reasonable way to check if the update matched an existing user. Although if you aren't using transactions, you should be aware that the user may not exist at the time of the update, but a separate connection could insert the user before your select.

   That said, without transactions there is always a chance that the select will return the object in a different state from the update you just performed. It is slightly worse in this case, though, because technically the update should have failed.
2. If you don't need the update to return the updated object in the response, then options 2 seems like a much better solution. For this to work, though, you need the update to return the number of matched rows rather than the number of changed rows (so if the update matches an existing user, but the field you are updating doesn't change, you'll still get a non-zero result).

   Usually you would have to set a connection attribute to make this work for MySQL (for example, in PHP's PDO driver there is the `MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` attribute). However, my understanding is that this option is [already enabled in JDBC](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,25956,25960#msg-25960) so `executeUpdate` should return the number of matched rows. I can't confirm that at the moment, but it should be easy enough for you to test.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with option 3 for the reusability and sanity aspect, unless you're worried about a couple of extra queries for (very strict and not obvious) performance reasons.

Since you'll likely reuse the code to retrieve the user in other places, I'd first retrieve the user, and return a 404 if he's not found. Then I'd call update and sanity check the number of rows changed. Finally, I'd call the retrieval method to get the user and marshall it into the response body. It's simple, it works, it's readable, it's predictable, it's testable, and it's most likely fast enough. And you've just reused your retrieval method.

Answer (score 2):

Best approach in your case is to run a select query against given id in order to verify that a corresponding record exists in your database. If record exists, then you can proceed with success flow and run the update and the select queries you mentioned above. Otherwise, if record does not exists, then you can proceed with the failure flow (throw exceptions etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Here is how I tackled the issue

1. Whenever its a new user, then mark the id with a default number (eg. 51002122) here 51002122 is never the id in db. So the page shows "/51002122/user". When ever the id of the user is 51002122 then I would do an insert to db. After the insert, I render the page with the id from db. Eg. after insertion,  the page would be "/27/user".
2. For all other ids other than 51002122  ( eg. /12/user or /129/user ) I would do an update in the db because I know that this user exists in the db.

Not sure if this is the right approach but this works. Can someone tell a better or correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most safe way is:

```
SELECT EXISTS(
             SELECT *
             FROM users
             WHERE id =  3 ) as columnCount;
```

This will return the number of rows that have id=3. Then you can return this and check if the columnCount is 1, then execute the update statement else do something else.

Answer (score 1):

Before arriving at a solution, few things needs to be considered.

1. This is a REST API call that calls for **simplicity** from the usage perspective.
2. The server side code should also consider the **performance** implication of the implementation chosen.
3. The API should be **robust**. Meaning, come what may, the request should always take the flows(happy/exception) conceived in design.

Based on these considerations, I would suggest the following approach.

1. In the DAO, define two different methods, namely `updateRecord(Long id, String username)` and `getRecord(Long id)`.
2. Mark transaction attribute (`@Transaction`) to these method as follows

   - Mark transaction attribute for `updateRecord` as `REQUIRED`.
   - Mark transaction attribute for `getRecord` as `NOT_REQUIRED` since this is purly a read call.
3. Note that in all the cases, at least on DB call is required.
4. From controller, call `updateRecord` method first. This method will return an integer.
5. If the returned value is nonzero, then call `getRecord` to retrieve the updated record from database.
6. If the returned value is zero, that indicates the user does not exists and no need to call `getRecord`. An appropriate error response (404 Not Found ) to the returned to the calling client.
7. In this approach, you will save on one database call when the user does not exist.

Overall this approach is neat, less cluttered and most importantly simple and efficient(*We are limiting transaction boundary only for update call*). Moreover `getRecord` can be used independently as another API to retrieve a record (*without transaction*).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where I was supposed to update a table but before that need to check if the id exists or not. I used openjpa and wrote method verifyUser(id) where id was the one which i need to check. OpenJpa findById returns u the record. On update it returns you the complete record whereas on add it returns you the new primary key by which the record is added. I am not sure how it works for hibernate but there are many similarities in jpa n hibernate.